# Recommended resources or tuts for Bitcoin/Bitcoin Exchange clone using Ruby/Rails?

Tags: blockchain, ruby

Are there any reputable resources or tuts for re-building a Bitcoin/Bitcoin Exchange clone using Ruby/Rails (e.g. Michael Hartl tutorial)? I would like to experiment and learn more about blockchain transactions.  Thank you!

Comment: Bitcoin is the easy part of an exchange, dealing with the currency on the other side is what costs significant time and money. The amount of paperwork required when dealing with other peoples USD is quite mind blowing.

Comment: I'll settle for any useful resources/tutorials concerning Bitcoin & Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest Ruby-related Bitcoin project is Toshi by Coinbase.

You can obviously read through [the source code](https://github.com/coinbase/toshi). And read through the [documentation](https://github.com/coinbase/toshi/tree/master/docs) in the github repo.

There's also [bitcoin-ruby](http://bitcoin-ruby.org/) which should get you started on how to program bitcoin stuff using Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the recos, Jimmy!  I actually had a much easier time getting acquainted under the hood with Python via [PracticalDev's SnakeCoin tutorial](https://dev.to/aunyks/lets-build-the-tiniest-blockchain), which I then retooled for a variation of Node now on my [GitHub](https://github.com/alexanderjsingleton/crypto-cuck-coin).